# read data from file using loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a raw data file with 100 records. 
Name - Start position is 0.
Address - Start position is 50.

I want to read this data[name and address] and do validation and store the information in DB.
Please suggest how this can be achieved with loopback.

Comment: You can use the node.js file system functions to read the file. However, what's the trigger for actually reading the file and updating the database? Is this only going to be done once? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: From the external source i will receive the the data in CSV/XLS/XML format. I need to read each column data, validate and update the DB. Files which i receive from external source will contain multiple rows[records] . i need to iterate to each row and get the field details.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to add a remote method to one of your models to do the actual import and then use some packages like '[csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv)' and '[xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml)' from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) to read the files. So, the basic steps are:

1. Add a remote method to an existing model
2. Add packages from npm to read the actual files
3. Read the through the files and update the database.

Something like this:

```
// MyModel.js
import fs = require('fs');
import xml = require('xml')
import csv = require('csv')

export function import(info, callback) {

    // Get the current database connection.
    var ds = this.dataSource.connector;

    // ***********************************************
    // ** READ FILES AND WRITE TO THE DATABASE HERE **
    // ***********************************************
    // --->
    // ***********************************************

    // Return results and/or error information.
    return callback(null, data)
}

export function remoteMethod(model: any) {
    model.remoteMethod(
        'import',
        {
            http: { verb: 'get' },
            accepts: {arg: 'info', type: 'data' },
            returns: [
                { arg: 'info', type: 'data' },
                { arg: 'data', type: 'data' }
            ]
        }
    )
    return model;
}
```

This would be called using http://mydomain/api/myModel/import using a 'get'.